# Is a batsman out bowled if they kick the ball onto the wicket?

Tags: rules, cricket

Consider a stituation where a batsman plays at a ball and the ball hits his pad. The ball becomes momentarily stationary and behind him.

The batsman is out of his crease and while he is attempting to regain his ground (to avoid being run out), he ends up kicking the ball onto the stumps and removes a bail before a fielder has collected it.

Is the batsman out bowled, out by any other means or not out?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, out bowled. [Law 32.1.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-32-bowled/):

> The striker is out Bowled if his/her wicket is put down by a ball delivered by the bowler, not being a No ball, even if it first touches the striker’s bat or person.

Note that the ball becoming stationary does not cause it to be dead; [Law 20.1](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-20-dead-ball/):

> 20.1.1 The ball becomes dead when
>
> 20.1.1.1 it is finally settled in the hands of the wicket-keeper or of the bowler.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> 20.1.2 The ball shall be considered to be dead when it is clear to the bowler’s end umpire that the fielding side and both batsmen at the wicket have ceased to regard it as in play.

In this case, as the batsman was trying to avoid being run out, so he clearly did not regard the ball as no longer being in play.